# How to change/update a label in Neo4j - Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to change a label on a node using Cypher? 
I have a node with label `Book`, as shown below. I want to change the `Book` label to `DeletedBook`.

```
(u:Person)-[r]-(b:Book{id:id1})

(u:Person)-[r]-(b:DeletedBook{id:id1})
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do that using `REMOVE` on the `Book` label and `SET` on the new label:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r]-(b:Book {id: id1})
REMOVE b:Book
SET b:DeletedBook
RETURN b
```

You should check out the [Neo4j Cypher Refcard](http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.0/) for a complete reference to Cypher 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'REMOVE' for removing and SET for adding new label.

eg:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r]-(b:Book {id: id1})
REMOVE b:Book
SET b:DeletedBook
RETURN b
```

Best practice is to add a 'delete' label to the node we want to delete.
Don't remove the label of a node when we update.

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r]-(b:Book {id: id1})
SET b: Deleted
RETURN b
```

so book node will have 2 labels (:Book:Deleted)