# Cypher query: Set nodes properties to lowercase

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have some tag nodes with a name property. After a while I started creating them with name in lowercase to avoid multiple instances of the same tag with different letters (ex: tag, Tag, etc).

I would like to update existing tags with uppercase names and set them to lowercase, is this possible with a cypher query?

Comment: By tag, you mean labels? If yes, then you need to remove existing and set new labels. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056127/how-to-change-update-a-label-in-neo4j-cypher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
MATCH (tag:Tag)
WHERE exists(tag.name) AND tag.name =~ '.*\\p{Lu}.*'
SET tag.name = lower(tag.name)
RETURN tag.name, lower(tag.name)
```

If you want *all* tag properties to be lowercase you could simply skip the regex check, but just for completeness, this should match anything that contains an uppercase-class character (`\p{Lu}`).

As always, you should backup your DB before running this kind of destructive change!

Comment: That did it! Tried it on a local copy of the database of course ;) thanks